# Tablet losing connection when switching to another router

Tags: wireless, access-point, network-access, network

Our organization has a very long hall way. I have two WiFi routers in the hall, 1 on the West end and one on the East end. When an employee walks from West end to the east in, the tablet switches to the east end WiFi router and drops the network connection  for a split second.

The program we use on the tablet has a very low packet loss threshold. This means, the program will kick you out if any packets are lost. I believe we are losing the pack when the tablet switches to the other WiFi router.

Switching to the other WiFi router is fine, that is what I want it to do to extend the range of the wireless network. I set the WiFi routers up with the same SSID and password so if users on the West end walk to the east end they would have internet.

Is it possible to have the tablet switch from the West WiFi Router to the East WiFi router without dropping it's connection for that split second ?

For your information, these WiFi routers are in wifi mode and leasing out IP addresses to the tablets. Do I need some type of extender or need to run them in AP mode ?

How have you and other organizations solved this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: You keep using the word "router" instead of "access point". Do you mean that those devices are actually in different IP networks?

Comment: no, I will go back and fix this. The reason I don't say access point is because they are not in AP mode. These are regular WiFi Routers.

Comment: What are the router models and configurations?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in WiFi it is up to the client to decide when and how to roam from one access point (AP) to another. Additional 802.11 standards, like 802.11 r,k,v are meant to help the client in selecting the best AP and then to smoothly roam to it. Sadly, those protocols are rarely implemented in consumer routers/APs. In addition, they work well only on a network with same-vendor APs.

In order to have a smooth roaming experience:

- Make sure both APs are in the same IP network, use same SSID, same encryption scheme
- Leave enough coverage overlapping between the two APs
- Use APs from the **same vendor** and supporting **802.11rkv**. Avoid residential products, as they are unlikely to support those roaming protocols. Avoid different brands at the same time. Ubiquiti makes some cheap semi-professional APs that support 802.11r (fast roaming), as documented [here](https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004662107-UniFi-Fast-Roaming).
- Use clients that support 802.11rkv. For example, you can find out which Apple products support it  [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202628). This is also a nice and quick read to get a rough idea of what these protocols do.